# Carriage returns are missing from asynchronous output while waiting for input via TTY::Prompt#ask

Tags: ruby, stdout

I'm writing a command-line application that has a CLI interface with a prompt. While waiting for user input, log messages from a WEBRick server are being written to STDOUT asynchronously.

I'm using `TTY::Prompt#ask` to render the prompt and handle user input. While `TTY:Prompt#ask` is blocking in one thread, output to STDOUT from another thread is getting messed up.

```
t = Thread.new do
  TTY::Prompt.new.ask('=>')
end

sleep 2

puts "one with no \\r"
puts "two with no \\r"
puts "three with no \\r"

puts "\rone with \\r"
puts "\rtwo with \\r"
puts "\rthree with \\r"
t.join
```

I thought this might have to do with malformed escapes for coloring, so I disabled color on the prompt and still had the same results.

Output:

```
=> one with no \r
                 two with no \r
                               three with no \r
one with \r
two with \r
three with \r
```

Output using `Kernel#readline`. This is output from the same code, except `TTY::Prompt.new.ask('=>')` has been replaced with `print =>; readline`:

```
=>one with no \r
two with no \r
three with no \r
one with \r
two with \r
three with \r
```

I'm running:

- OS version: WSL2 Ubuntu (kernel 4.19.84-microsoft-standard)
- Ruby version: 2.7.0p0
- TTY version: 0.21.0

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Your title isn't well written; It should be a clear, concise statement, not a question. It describes "how to" do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You shouldn't try to write asynchronously to the same device you're reading from; You're creating a terrible user-experience. The simplest thing is to route the log to a file, or open a second terminal session and let the log scroll there. Alternately, you can play terminal/ANSI games and set up a scrolling region that sits above or below your input area, but that can lead down a rabbit-hole. I strongly recommend using a file. If the user needs to see its contents, they can `tail -f` it.

Comment: The UX isn't terribly important for the CLI. The main way the user interacts with the application is through a website. The CLI is only for simple management/monitoring when a browser isn't accessible (ie. the console of a headless server). Other UX imperfections such as output hiding the prompt are acceptable, but this specific problem is a significant one since it makes exception backtraces practically unreadable.

Comment: Well, as a long-time *nix guy, _I_ find it perfectly acceptable to tail a log in one terminal window and use another for my input. There are lots of tools to let the screen multitask, but simple was always better for me.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I can't imagine life without tmux, but can't make the assumption that the end user is going to be comfortable enough with *nix to know that. I'm more or less trying to make a terminal multiplexer exclusively for input/ouput streams yielded from Open3#popen2e in background threads. On paper that sounds like a mess but I pretty much have all the functionality I want minus this carriage return problem.